# Re Toggle / Re add the class of a variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, audio

I am devoloping a master control panel for an audio player, Everything works fine except for if I play another track while one track is already playing then hit stop on the master control then hit play again on the master control it doesn't add the class ".pause" back to the track.
JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffd/2fjnmdkb/15/

```
    $(".play").on('click', function () {
     var key = $(this).attr('key');
     var nowplay = $(this); // variable for now playing class .play
     EvalSound(this, key);
     $(".play").not(this).removeClass("pause");     
     $(this).toggleClass("pause");
     $(this).hasClass("pause") ? $(".playerbottom").addClass("pausebottom") : $(".playerbottom").removeClass("pausebottom");
 $(".playerbottom").on('click', function () {
   nowplay.toggleClass("pause");   
$(".play").not(nowplay).removeClass("pause");

 }); 

});
 var thissound = new Audio();
 var currentKey;
 function EvalSound(el, key) {
     thissound.addEventListener('ended', function () {
         // done playing
         $(el).removeClass("pause");
         $(".playerbottom").removeClass("pausebottom");
     });
     if (currentKey !== key) thissound.src = "http://99centbeats.com/1e4cb5f584d055a0992385c1b2155786/" + key;
     currentKey = key;
     if (thissound.paused) thissound.play();
     else thissound.pause();
     currentPlayer = thissound;
 }

$(".volume_slider").slider({
    value  : 75,
    step   : 1,
    range  : 'min',
    min    : 0,
    max    : 100,
    slide  : function(){
        var value = $(".volume_slider").slider("value");
        thissound.volume = (value / 100);
    }
}); 
 $(".playerbottom").on('click', function () {
     $(this).toggleClass("pausebottom");
     if (thissound.paused) thissound.play();
     else thissound.pause();

 });
```

Comment: nowplay is not defined?

Comment: `nowPlay` not defined at `$(".playerbottom").on('click'` ?

Comment: It's a scoping issue. Move the declaration of `nowplay` outside of all your functions and that should fix it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2fjnmdkb/11/ ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffd/2fjnmdkb/14/ - there is still somthing a little messed up with the toggling but this is close

Answer (score 0):

after making nowplay a global variable it works:  window.nowplay = $(this);

Working Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffd/2gbz7agp/

```
    $(".play").on('click', function () {
     var key = $(this).attr('key');
     window.nowplay = $(this); // variable for now playing class .play
     EvalSound(this, key);
     $(".play").not(this).removeClass("pause");     
     $(this).toggleClass("pause");
     $(this).hasClass("pause") ? $(".playerbottom").addClass("pausebottom") : $(".playerbottom").removeClass("pausebottom");
 $(".playerbottom").on('click', function () {
      $(this).hasClass("pausebottom") ? nowplay.addClass("pause") : nowplay.removeClass("pause");

 }); 

});
 var thissound = new Audio();
 var currentKey;
 function EvalSound(el, key) {
     thissound.addEventListener('ended', function () {
         // done playing
         $(el).removeClass("pause");
         $(".playerbottom").removeClass("pausebottom");
     });
     if (currentKey !== key) thissound.src = "http://99centbeats.com/1e4cb5f584d055a0992385c1b2155786/" + key;
     currentKey = key;
     if (thissound.paused) thissound.play();
     else thissound.pause();
     currentPlayer = thissound;
 }

$(".volume_slider").slider({
    value  : 75,
    step   : 1,
    range  : 'min',
    min    : 0,
    max    : 100,
    slide  : function(){
        var value = $(".volume_slider").slider("value");
        thissound.volume = (value / 100);
    }
}); 
 $(".playerbottom").on('click', function () {
     $(this).toggleClass("pausebottom");
     if (thissound.paused) thissound.play();
     else thissound.pause();

 });
```